# How to see which line of code "next" would execute in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb

While debugging some code in gdb, I want to see which line will be executed if I say `next` or `step`.

- Of course I can say `l`, but if I say `l` a couple times (and don't remember how many times), then `l` does not print the line that will be executed.
- I can also scroll back to the last time gdb stopped and see which line it was at, but that sometimes involve digging through a bunch of output.

I am wondering if I am missing a simple command in gdb which shows me the current line the debugger is stopped at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run `GDB` in `Emacs` (which will show you current file and mark the current line), in `DDD`, or in `tui` mode.

Comment: I have never used TUI mode before, but I am going to look into it now. Looks useful. :-)

Comment: `tui` mode is awesome. I had always wanted something like that, but did not know that it existed. I knew about DDD but I usually debug on a remote server and DDD requires X display. So, `tui` mode is great. Thanks for the information. By the way, `update` command in `tui` mode is the one solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

To see the current line the debugger stopped at, you can use `frame` command with no arguments. This achieves the same effect as `update` command. It works both in `tui` and command line mode.

Comment: I suppose you mean `frame`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> list *$eip

or the shorter form

> l *$eip

This will instruct gdb to print the source lines near the current program counter.

Comment: T: I see the register $rip, but not $eip? And did you mean `p` instead of `l`? `p $eip` gives `void` and `p *$eip` tells me that I am attempting to take contents of a non-pointer value.

Comment: @Yogi If you're working with a 64-bit processor the program counter will be `$rip` instead of `$eip`. Try `list *$rip`. The asterisk before the register is needed; it tells gdb to treat the value as an address.

Comment: Yes, that does indeed give me the line number. Thank you! By the way, I just noticed that `info frame` also prints out this information. 
I wish I could accept two answers!

Comment: @yogi glad to have helped. While you can't accept 2 answers, you can upvote :)

Comment: `$pc` is a shorthand for `$eip` or `$rip` -- GDB will substitute whatever register is correct. Works on other platforms as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can say `l +0`; the current line will be the first one listed.

The command `l +offset` lists the code starting from `offset` lines from the current line.

Note that, if you have already used the `list` command, the current line will have changed, i.e., it will no longer be the next executing line. So this will only work on your first `list` command.

Comment: mkcs, after executing `l` a bunch of times, the "current line" changes, but the line that will be executed next does not. Giving a bunch of `l` commands does not change which line will be executed next. Or at not with 
GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.5-37.el5_2.2rh)

Comment: @Yogi: you are right. That's what I meant by "the current line will no longer be the next executing line". (I had tested the `l +0` before I posted the answer, but I retested it and it does not seem to work. I'm confused.)

Comment: @Yogi: Okay, since the command will only the first time you run it, I realize now that my answer is useless for you. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your time nonetheless. :-)